# align-items: center changing the width of a child element

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Somehow if I put items-center for the parent, a child element changes its width.

I use tailwind CSS.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="flex flex-col items-center">
    <div class="mx-5">
      <div class="flex max-w-xl mx-auto border-solid border border-slate-300/50 h-10 ">
        <input type="text" class="bg-inherit outline-none">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: here's a suggestion: remove tailwind and bootstrap and just use css  and see if the problem happens there. If so, look into flex documentation. If not, add bootstrap and repeat. If the problem now happens look into bootstrap.  If  not, remove bootstrap and add tailwind. if the problem doesn't occur it's likely the interaction between bootstrap and tailwind.  I mention bootstrap as some of your classes look like bootstrap classes.  good luck

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by changes width? But I am going to guess you are trying to center the child? Flex box will only center an element if the element width is less than the parent width. See my snippet below. If the input is 100% width it won't center. If you are talking the child width changes it should as I am pretty sure that is what tailwind does for responsiveness.

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.flex-wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
}

.flex-wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div>
    <span>One</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Two</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting a default `width`. I once had a similar problem with `align-items: center;` and I fixed it by setting the `width: 100px;`. IDK if it will work in your case but it worked in mine.

PS: you might want to edit your question to make it clearer, it helps other people understand your problem better which leads to better solutions.